# How can I find a GPS supported phone without an Internet support enable?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, gps, lost-phone

Can I still find my phone's location even without Internet? Because as I know, GPS support will be enable if the phone's Internet is active. So is there a way how to find it? Because today, someone stole my phone. And I don't know if I can still find it. Is there a way how can I start the GPS from remote?

Comment: GPS activation is not connected to Internet settings/activation. So if you didn't install any specific app before, and your device has no network connection, that's not possible AFAIK. For existing solutions, please take a look at our [lost-phone tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/lost-phone/info).

Comment: If your phone never connects to the Internet again and you don't already have something installed that can be activated through SMS, then there is nothing you can do. You could try to install Android Lost remotely (press the install button in the Play Store) and hope that the phone will at some point come online again while logged into your Google account; then it will install. Maybe use Android Lost Jumpstart first, not sure how that works. At any rate, good luck...